# AngularJS - Number format xxx-xx-xxxx

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a filter, which matches the number format `xxx-xx-xxxx` ie. 123-12-1234.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4P7wD/)

```
angular.module('ng').filter('tel', function () {
    return function (tel) {
        if (!tel) { return ''; }

        var value = tel.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return tel;
        }

        var country, city, number;

        switch (value.length) {
            case 9: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
                country = 1;
                city = value.slice(0, 3);
                number = value.slice(4);
                break;

            default:
                return tel;
        }

        if (country == 1) {
            country = "";
        }

        number = number.slice(0, 2) + '-' + number.slice(3);

        return (country + " " + city + "-" + number).trim();
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope){
    $scope.phoneNumber =  111223333;
}
```

Can somebody help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4P7wD/1/
Change one digit.

```
number = number.slice(0, 2) + '-' + number.slice(1);
```

**UPDATED**
Hope it is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/4P7wD/2/

Comment: the result comes like this `111-23-3333`... it should be `111-22-3333`

Comment: Ok, you did not notice anything about sort of number. Thought you need just format.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean::

```
...
switch (value.length) {
    case 9: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
        country = 1;
        city = value.slice(0, 3);
        number = value.slice(3);
        break;        

        default:
            return tel;
    }

    if (country == 1) {
        country = "";
    }

    number = number.slice(0, 2) + '-' + number.slice(2);

    return (city + "-" + number).trim();
...
```

Demo:: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4P7wD/3/)